# Automatically hide header on screen when not rich height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is a screen with search bar.

When I swipe FlatList to top - search bar moves to top and hides behind the header of screen - it works fine.

BUT when I switch screens with my tab navigation (to left tab and back to right tab) and if the seach bar is on half-visible position, after switching on right tab threr is generated space.. looks like coordinates of search bar is wrong after moving between screens.

I want to resolve it like in whatsapp search bar in chatlist screen - when I didnt opened it more then 50% it goes back and closes, and conversely with opening search bar (when didnt opened more then 50% its closes automatically).

please if you know how to resolve it, help me, big thank you!

[image: bug when switch screens]

there is my screen.js, and link on [github project](https://github.com/ArturScwaiberov/react-native-dental-app)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useFocusEffect, useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { Animated, FlatList, RefreshControl, Alert, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { Octicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { RectButton } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable'
import { Header, Item, Input, Icon } from 'native-base'

import { patientsApi } from '../utils'
import { Patient } from '../src/components'

const PatientsListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
    const ref = React.useRef(null)
    const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)
    const [animatedValue, setAnimatedValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            cleanFetch()
        }, [])
    )

    useScrollToTop(ref)

    const cleanFetch = () => {
        patientsApi
            .get()
            .then(({ data }) => {
                setData(data.message)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                error.request ? console.log(error.request) : console.log('Error', error.message)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setRefreshing(false)
            })
    }

    const fetchPatients = () => {
        setRefreshing(true)
        cleanFetch()
    }

    useEffect(fetchPatients, [])

    const removePatient = (id) => {
        Alert.alert(
            'Удаление пациента',
            'Вы действительно хотите удалить пациента и его приемы?',
            [
                {
                    text: 'Отмена',
                    style: 'cancel',
                },
                {
                    text: 'Да, удалить',
                    onPress: () => {
                        const result = data.filter((item) => item._id !== id)
                        setData(result)
                        patientsApi.remove(id)
                    },
                    style: 'default',
                },
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
        )
    }

    renderRightAction = (text, color, x, progress, id) => {
        const trans = progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [x, 0],
        })

        const pressHandler = () => {
            if (text === 'pencil') {
                navigation.navigate('EditPatient')
            } else {
                removePatient(id)
            }
        }

        return (
            <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, transform: [{ translateX: trans }] }}>
                <RectButton
                    style={{
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        flex: 1,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        backgroundColor: color,
                    }}
                    onPress={pressHandler}
                >
                    <ActionText>
                        <Octicons name={text} size={24} color='white' />
                    </ActionText>
                </RectButton>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }

    renderRightActions = (progress, id) => (
        <RightButtonsHandler>
            {renderRightAction('pencil', '#B4C1CB', 160, progress, id)}
            {renderRightAction('trashcan', '#F85A5A', 80, progress, id)}
        </RightButtonsHandler>
    )

    const onSearch = (e) => {
        setSearchValue(e.nativeEvent.text)
    }

    let translateY = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 44],
        outputRange: [0, -60],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
    })

    return (
        <Container>
            {data ? (
                <>
                    <AnimatedFlatList
                        scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}
                        ref={ref}
                        style={{ paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20 }}
                        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 55, flexGrow: 1 }}
                        scrollEventThrottle={16} // <-- Use 1 here to make sure no events are ever missed
                        onScroll={Animated.event(
                            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: animatedValue } } }],
                            { useNativeDriver: true } // <-- Add this
                        )}
                        data={data.filter(
                            (item) => item.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <Swipeable
                                renderRightActions={(progress) => renderRightActions(progress, item._id)}
                                friction={2}
                            >
                                <Patient navigation={navigation} item={item} />
                            </Swipeable>
                        )}
                        refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={cleanFetch} />}
                        ListEmptyComponent={
                            <ActionText style={{ color: 'red', padding: 0 }}>
                                Такой пациент не найден..
                            </ActionText>
                        }
                    />
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[
                            { position: 'absolute', height: 60, left: 0, right: 0 },
                            { transform: [{ translateY }] },
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Header searchBar rounded style={{ paddingTop: 0, height: 61 }}>
                            <Item>
                                <Icon name='ios-search' />
                                <Input placeholder='Поиск...' clearButtonMode='always' onChange={onSearch} />
                                <Icon name='ios-people' />
                            </Item>
                        </Header>
                    </Animated.View>
                </>
            ) : (
                <ActionText style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    Пожалуйста проверьте соединение с сервером...
                </ActionText>
            )}
        </Container>
    )
}

const Container = styled.SafeAreaView({
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
})

const RightButtonsHandler = styled.View({
    width: 160,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginLeft: 20,
})

const ActionText = styled.Text({
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    padding: 10,
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerWrapper: {},
})

export default PatientsListScreen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im so sorry for this question!

It was my error, I should connect Animated with dot like this:

```
<Animated.FlatList
...
```

and I did it like this with creating const:

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)
...
<AnimatedFlatList
...
```

So this component worked wrong..

It was my fault, so I close this question, thanks for everyone!